# Restrict user access to certain apps in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have a simple goal, create a local account and limit its rights:

1. Hide & Secure certain folders/partitions.
2. Limit access to certain apps.

For restricting App access, I've only found some tutorials based on editing the registries. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Will your local account be a normal user or an administrator? This is important to think about, because if it is just a normal user you can easily just remove it from the properties of the application, thereby making it impossible for the user to run the application. It is a whole other story if your user is going to be administrator, because then you can basically never *really* block him out.

Comment: @Bungicasse Just a normal user :)

Comment: Okay, if you go into Properties --> Security of any given application and remove the user from the list he will no longer be able to execute that application. Same goes for folders/partitions, just remove him from the properties and access will be denied.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AppLocker or software restriction policy to limit a user or group to access certain apps:

AppLocker

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/applocker/applocker-overview

Administer Software Restriction Policies

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994606(v=ws.11).aspx